# have or has after who in sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

1.one of the boys who "has/have" met the prime minister is absent

2. one of the boys represent singular.what should we use in sentence have or has?

Comment: my teacher mentioned "have" is appropriate. but i have doubt in it

Comment: Plural "have": there is a set of boys who have met the Prime Minister and one member of this set is absent. (Thus the relative clause modifies "boys").

Comment: thank you very much billj